# Illegal state exception when DialogFragment is injected using Hilt

Tags: android, android-fragments, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt, dialogfragment

App crashes, when application comes to foreground on CustomDialog Fragment transaction.

Hello everyone, I am using Hilt to inject a dialog fragment instance, which is shown on API response. If user push application to background and then bring it to foreground, then app crashes while showing the dialog fragment on api response. This issue resolves if the fragment instance is created manually. Thanks in advance for your help.[Instance of DialogFragment injected through hilt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7vam.png)
[Custom Dialog Fragment Class Header that was injected using hilt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtPY9.png)

[Fragment being utilized on api response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxBR3.png)

[error while showing the fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVD7B.png)

Comment: You are not injecting anything insdie constructor.

Comment: Please share more code for better understanding. I am not clear about your implementation. I need full class of Dialog Fragment and also that class in which you want to inject dialog fragment.

Comment: Thanks for response, because I need a default constructor, that's why not passing anything inside the constructor.

Comment: Can you please share your class where you want to inject DialogFragment.